# Issue with calling a component's function while rendering inside a multiple ternary expression - react

Tags: reactjs, jsx, conditional-operator

So, I have 8 different components which contain data about 8 categories of products (pc components), which obviously have different values in the description (core count, etc.).

Those 8 components only contain the specific data (processor contains core count, but does not contain price - every component has a price irrespective of category)

In product.jsx, I want to render one of the 8 components depending of the categoryName, which I get by calling a function I define in the component's body (getCategory). However, for some reason, the getCategory function is never evaluated, no console.log is ever printed in the console from that function.

Just to point out, if I just render < Processor />, the data is displayed, and if the comparation for the 1st is "processor"==="processor" (always true), then the data is again displayed.

I think my error is in react logic. Somehow I am missing something on how react renders stuff. Can you please spot the error in my use of React. Thank you!

Below you will find the code of the component in question, but a full repo can be found here: https://github.com/vradu007/radu-shop

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Layout from "../../components/Layout/Layout";
import products from "../../utils/products.json";
import "./Product.css";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { addToCart } from "../../redux/cart/cartAction";
import { addToFavourites } from "../../redux/favourites/favouritesAction";
import { Processor, VideoCard, PowerSupply, Storage, Ram, Motherboard } from "../../utils/ProductItemsData";


const Product = (props) => {
    const [product, setProduct] = useState({});
    const { match } = props;
    const productId = match.params.productId;

    const categoryValues = Object.values(products);
    
    //unreachable
    const getCategory = () => {
        categoryValues.forEach((category) => {
            category.items.forEach((item)=> {
                if(item.id === productId){
                    return category;
                }
            })
        })
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        const productItems = categoryValues.reduce((acc, category) => {
            return [...acc, ...category.items];
        }, []);
        const currentProduct = productItems.find((product) => {
            return Number(productId) === product.id;
        });
        setProduct(currentProduct);
    }, [props]);
    

    return (
        <Layout>
            <div className="product-page container-fluid container-min-max-width">
                <h1 className="my-5 h2">{product.name}</h1>
                <div className="product-info d-flex">
                    <div className="image-wrapper d-flex mr-5">
                        <img src={product.image} alt="Product presentation" />
                    </div>
                    <div className="product-details">
                        <p className="h3 text-danger">
                            {product.price} {product.currency}
                        </p>
                        <div>
                            <button
                                className="btn btn-dark mb-4 font-weight-bold"
                                onClick={() => {
                                    props.addToCart({
                                        product: {
                                            id: product.id,
                                            name: product.name,
                                            price: product.price,
                                            currency: product.currency,
                                            image: product.image,
                                        },
                                    });
                                }}
                            >
                                Add to cart
                            </button>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <button
                                className="btn btn-dark mb-4 font-weight-bold"
                                onClick={() => {
                                    props.addToFavourites({
                                        product: {
                                            id: product.id,
                                            name: product.name,
                                            price: product.price,
                                            currency: product.currency,
                                            image: product.image,
                                        },
                                    });
                                }}
                            >
                                Add to favourites
                            </button>
                        </div>
                        {
                            getCategory()==="processor"?
                                <Processor
                                    baseFrequency={product.baseFrequency}
                                    boostFrequency={product.boostFrequency}
                                    cores={product.cores}
                                    threads={product.threads}
                                    description={product.description}
                                />
                            : getCategory()==="video-card"?
                                <VideoCard
                                    baseFrequency={product.baseFrequency}
                                    boostFrequency={product.boostFrequency}
                                    cores={product.cores}
                                    threads={product.threads}
                                    description={product.description}
                                />
                            : getCategory()==="motherboard"?
                                <Motherboard
                                    baseFrequency={product.baseFrequency}
                                    boostFrequency={product.boostFrequency}
                                    cores={product.cores}
                                    threads={product.threads}
                                    description={product.description}
                                />
                            : getCategory()==="ram"?
                                <Ram
                                    baseFrequency={product.baseFrequency}
                                    boostFrequency={product.boostFrequency}
                                    cores={product.cores}
                                    threads={product.threads}
                                    description={product.description}
                                />
                            : getCategory()==="storage"?
                                <Storage
                                    baseFrequency={product.baseFrequency}
                                    boostFrequency={product.boostFrequency}
                                    cores={product.cores}
                                    threads={product.threads}
                                    description={product.description}
                                />
                            : getCategory()==="power-supply"?
                                <PowerSupply
                                    baseFrequency={product.baseFrequency}
                                    boostFrequency={product.boostFrequency}
                                    cores={product.cores}
                                    threads={product.threads}
                                    description={product.description}
                                />
                            : null
                        }
                        
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </Layout>
    );
};

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
        addToCart: (payload) => dispatch(addToCart(payload)),
        addToFavourites: (payload) => dispatch(addToFavourites(payload)),
    };
}

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(Product);
```

Comment: It looks like `getCategory` returns an object not the string you are expecting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it is currently written, your `getCategory` function "returns" `undefined`, since it has no return statement, and there is no implicit return because you are using `{}`. It should be *called*, it just doesn't return anything from the inner loop.

Also note that [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) does not have a return value, so you need to rethink how you find the inner category (and not use `forEach`). If appropriate I would also recommend that you set the result from `getCategory` to a variable and switch over that, as to not calculate the category value multiple times in your render.

One way of doing this is by using the `useMemo` hook instead, and skip the `getCategory` function. Instead of using the `forEach` function, simply using a for loop instead lets you return something from the inner loop.

```js
const category = useMemo(() => {
  for (const category of categoryValues) {
    for (const item of category.items) {
      if (item.id === productId) {
        return category;
      }
    }
  }
  return undefined;
}, [categoryValues, productId])
```

This can be simplified with the [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) function on an Array, which takes a predicate and returns the first item that match. We're looking for the first category that has an item id with the product ID, so we can use the [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) function which returns `true` if *any* item in an array match a predicate:

```js
// useMemo takes a function that is called when its dependencies change.
// we use a lambda - () => expression - so the return value is implicit
const category = useMemo(() => 
  categoryValues.find(category => category.items.some(item => item.id === productId))
  // You can use destructuring instead if you find that more readable
  // categoryValues.find(category => category.items.some(({ id }) => id === productId))
), [categoryValues, productId])
```

Now with the `useMemo` hook the value is only recalculated when either `categoryValues` or `productId` changes.

And now you should be able to use the `category` variable instead of `getCategory()` in your render to get your desired effect. Remember that you should compare with the type or name rather than the *category* item, since that is an object.

```jsx
<>
  {category.name === "processor" ? <Processor />
   : category.name === "video-card" ? <VideoCard />
   // ...
   : <span>Could not find a suitable category</span>}
</>
```

---

As a side note since you are using hooks, instead of `connect` you can also get a dispatcher for actions using the `useDispatch` hook.

```js
const dispatch = useDispatch();
dispatch(addToCard(payload));
```

This is outside the scope of the question though, but personally I like this approach more in order to avoid `props` as much as possible.